# Scroll snap css property with overflow y is causing page scroll

Tags: css, safari

I'm using the css property [scroll-snap-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-type) to have contents of an overflowing div snap to place on scroll.

It's easily applied:

```
.container {
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
}

.contents {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

Have a look at this page in **Safari 11+ on desktop** for an example - https://codepen.io/fionnbharra/full/PQZmav/ 
Scroll over the div on the left hand side of the page. Notice how the when scrolling finishes the div aligns to the top of the container. This is behaving as expected.

My problem is that it breaks when we have a long page - https://codepen.io/fionnbharra/full/oEbWeq/

Try scrolling over the same overflow div. Notice how the page body scrolls at the at the same time, meaning it's very difficult to see the original content scroll.

Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It is experimental technology only partial supported. Chrome doesn't support it now (2018-02-07). 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-type

You should use other styles for the moment. the scroll-snap family can be replaced with additional container relatively positioned.

https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-snappoints

Browsers generally don't implemented it or implemented partially. Use other CSS styles.

BTW. Use caniuse.com if you want to be sure the style is supported correctly.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'm aware of the browser support. I was asking specifically about Safari. Sadly, It looks like even there it's implemented poorly.

Comment: Yes, experimental technologies are experimental. Do not use experimental technologies and make cross-browser websites. As LAST sort: you can use JS for needed effect but please do not use DHTML if it is not "candidate recomendation" or recomendation or Living Standard for years.

You can use MDN as first. If there is visible a "flask" - it means experimental. 

Here is side effect of experimental technologies (mainly created by Safari/Chrome): https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2156 . Nobody has idea what to do it in that case.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the way Safari is doing it, while it's snapping the div, it propagates scroll events up the chain, causing the whole window to scroll, but considering how this is experimental technology, I'm not too surprised. One way to tackle this would be to set the the `html` element's `overflow` to `hidden` while we are scrolling using JavaScript, and reset it when we are done:

```js
const container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
const html = document.documentElement;

let scrollTimer = -1;
let locked = false;

function lock() {
  if (!locked) {
    locked = true;
    html.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  }
}

function unlock() {
  if (locked) {
    locked = false;
    html.style.overflow = '';
  }
}

container.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  if (scrollTimer !== -1) {
    clearTimeout(scrollTimer);
  }

  if (container.scrollTop <= 0 ||
      container.scrollTop >= container.scrollHeight - container.offsetHeight) {
    // if scrollbar reaches top or bottom, unlock
    unlock();
  } else {
    lock();
    // defer unlocking scroll
    scrollTimer = setTimeout(unlock, 150); // consider 150ms of inactivity to be the end of a scroll
  }
}, false);
```

```css
main {
  background: #D7FCD4;
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  height: 400px;
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
}

.contents {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.contents:nth-child(even) {background: #B68F40}
.contents:nth-child(odd) {background: #545454}

.more-stuff {
  background: linear-gradient(#30011E, #fff);
  border-left: 10px solid white;
  display: block;
  height: 2000px;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<main>

<div class="container">
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
</div>

<div class="more-stuff">
 </div>
  
</main>
```

Since most browsers don't support this as of now, you would want to use a JavaScript-based solution in production for now.